# How do I simplify component registration using Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, architecture, inversion-of-control, autofac

I am new in using Autofac and I want to simplify registering Installation of my Queries.  ie

```
Bootstrapper.Builder.RegisterType<TableOneQuery>().As<ITableOneQuery>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
Bootstrapper.Builder.RegisterType<TableTwoQuery>().As<ITableTwoQuery>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
Bootstrapper.Builder.RegisterType<TableThreeQuery>().As<ITableThreeQuery>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
Bootstrapper.Builder.RegisterType<TableFourQuery>().As<ITableFourQuery>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
Bootstrapper.Builder.RegisterType<TableFiveQuery>().As<IFiveOneQuery>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

The queries are of the same type and they follow this convention

```
public class TableOneQuery : ITableOneQuery
    {
        private readonly IGenericRepository<TableOne> _tableOneRepository;

        public TableOneQuery(
            IGenericRepository<TableOne> tableOneRepository)
        {
            _tableOneRepository = tableOneRepository;

        }
        public TableOneViewModel Get(int id)
        {
          .....
        }
        public IList<TableOneViewModel> GetAll()
        {
          .....
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to just register it once for its type?

BTW `Bootstrapper` is an `Autofac.ContainerBuilder`

Comment: Seems like it would make more sense to create a parent interface for each of your query interfaces and use it for open generic registration instead.

Comment: It might make more sense to define one generic abstraction over queries, such as explained [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dynamically-provided registrations](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#dynamically-provided-registrations) in Autofac include [assembly scanning](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/scanning.html) to find and register types automagically.

```
var dataAccess = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(dataAccess)
   .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Query"))
   .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Comment: Thanks for this it works.  I also have another question, how about registering class like this?   public abstract class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class.

Comment: Look up builder.RegisterGeneric for that.